# How to Use Dynamic Parameters in a powershell script, instead of a function

Tags: powershell

I am triying to get some dynamic validatesets in my powershell script like

**MyScript.ps1 -Parameter1 DynamicAttributeDefinedWithinRuntime**

All help I found is for Dynamic Parameters within a PowerShell Function like

**MyPowerShellFunction -Parameter1 DynamicAttributeDefinedWithinRuntime**

If I create a function within the script with the Dynamic Parameters can I get these to be used at the CLI when the script file is executed from a powershell window?

Comment: Same process as with a function - add a `dynamicparam` block at the root of the script file

Comment: as MathiasR.Jessen pointed out, you make your script look like a function. take everything in the function between the `function` line and the closing `}` and put that in a file. then call it as if it was a function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great tutorial on `Dynamic` `ValidateSet` parameters:
https://vexx32.github.io/2018/11/29/Dynamic-ValidateSet/

One method from that site is using a 2nd function:

```
function Get-ValidValues {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param($Path)

    (Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -File).Name
}

function Clear-FileInCurrentLocation {
    <#
    .synopsis
        Dynamic ValidateSet from: https://vexx32.github.io/2018/11/29/Dynamic-ValidateSet/
    #>
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess, ConfirmImpact = 'High')]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory)]
        [ArgumentCompleter(
            {
                param($Command, $Parameter, $WordToComplete, $CommandAst, $FakeBoundParams)
                Get-ValidValues -Path (Get-Location)
            }
        )]
        [ValidateScript(
            {
                $_ -in (Get-ValidValues -Path (Get-Location))
            }
        )]
        [string]
        $Path
    )

    Clear-Content -Path $Path
}
```